# Can I create multiple columns from a single group by mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to group my dataframe on a certain column and then apply a function to the grouped data that returns multiple columns.  By means of example, consider the following

```
Names = append(rep('Mark',10),rep('Joe',10))
Spend = rnorm(length(Names),50,0.5)

df <- data.frame(
  Names,
  Spend
)


get.mm <- function(data){


  return(list(median(data),mean(data)))
}
```

Here, `get.mm` returns a list of two numbers.  I would like to apply `get.mm` to `df %>% group_by(Names)` and have the result have two columns, one fo each output of the function.

The desired result should  be

```
  Names   median    mean
  <fctr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1    Joe 49.89284 49.9504
2   Mark 50.17244 50.0735
```

I've simplified the function here for means of demonstration, I know I could just do something like

```
df %>% group_by(Names) %>% summarise(median = median(Spend), mean = mean(Spend))
```

Comment: see `summarise_at()` and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

Comment: This blog post is very relevant: https://www.r-bloggers.com/programming-with-dplyr-by-using-dplyr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite `get.mm` so that it returns a data frame, then you can use `group_by %>% do`:

```
get.mm <- function(data){
    data.frame(median = median(data), mean = mean(data))
}

df %>% group_by(Names) %>% do(get.mm(.$Spend))  
# here . stands for a sub data frame with a unique Name, .$Spend passes the corresponding
# column to the function
```

---

A reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
Names = append(rep('Mark',10),rep('Joe',10))
Spend = rnorm(length(Names),50,0.5)
df <- data.frame(Names, Spend)

df %>% group_by(Names) %>% do(get.mm(.$Spend))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Names [2]
#   Names   median     mean
#  <fctr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1    Joe 50.24594 50.12442
#2   Mark 50.12829 50.06610

df %>% group_by(Names) %>% summarise(median = median(Spend), mean = mean(Spend))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   Names   median     mean
#  <fctr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1    Joe 50.24594 50.12442
#2   Mark 50.12829 50.06610
```

Comment: I'm not a dplyr-er very often, but is something like `df %>% group_by(Names) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean,median))`  acceptable?

Comment: @thelatemail That definitely works and a great option here. `group_by %>% do` is suitable when cases are more complicated as indicated by OP.